# Creating tokens from text with tags in java

Tags: java, xml

How tokenization can be achieved in Java for the below input?

The input is a text file and need to get the output as mentioned.

Sample Input:

```
<Person>Peter Cathery</Person> lives in 
<Location>Melbourne</Location>, 
<Location>Australia</Location>
. He is 50 years old and he spent 
<Money>$100000</Money> 
on his house and any kind of disputes on his house will be part of the jurisdiction of 
<Location>Melbourne</Location> 
police station. His date of birth: 
<Date>11-12-1982</Date> and he works for 
<Organization>IBM Corporation Ltd</Organization>.
```

Output required:

```
Token 1: Peter Cathery
Token 2: lives
Token 3: in
Token 4: Melbourne
Token 5: ,
```

---

Comment: Use a readily available XML parser, like that included in the defualt library...

Comment: Refer to a tutorial on how to parse XML files, you can check this link -->[How To Read XML File In Java – (DOM Parser)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: use jDom Parser... You can play with XMLs .. Works like a charm for requirements like yours. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/

Comment: Which part of the problem are you finding difficult?

Comment: I am able to parse the xml but how do I tokenise only the text which is not in tags

Comment: I am able to parse the xml but how do I tokenise only the text which is not in tags

Comment: What are you using??... SAX, DOM? or JDOM? ... In JDom get the list of all nodes and read their values.. every tag is a node..

Comment: I have been using SAX till now..need to explore JDOM more